# Proving the inequality $|\mathrm{tr}(AU)|\le \mathrm{tr}|A|$ in Uhlmann's theorem

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, mathematics, nielsen-and-chuang, fidelity

In Nielsen and Chuang, in the Fidelity section, (Lemma 9.5, page 410 in the 2002 edition), they prove the following.

$$ \mathrm{tr}(AU) = |\mathrm{tr}(|A|VU)| = |\mathrm{tr}(|A|^{1/2}|A|^{1/2}VU)| $$
$$ |\mathrm{tr}(AU)| \leq \sqrt{\mathrm{tr}|A| \mathrm{tr}(U^{\dagger}V^{\dagger}|A|VU)} = \mathrm{tr}|A|$$

First, is $|A|$ the positive matrix in the polar decomposition of $A$?
And second, apparently, the second equation comes from the first due to Cauchy Schwartz inequality of Hilbert-Schmidt.

How does the first expression lead to the second?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll give a couple of methods to do this:

1. ***(Using matrix inequalities)*** The idea is to use CS inequality in the form
   $$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{Tr}}\lvert \sum_{ij}A_{ij}^* B_{ij}\rvert\le\sqrt{\sum_{ij} \left\lvert A_{ij}\right\rvert^2}\sqrt{\sum_{ij}\left\lvert  B_{ij}\right\rvert^2},$$ which in matrix formalism reads $$\lvert\tr(A^\dagger B)\rvert\le\sqrt{\tr(A^\dagger A})\sqrt{\tr(B^\dagger B)}.$$
   Therefore,
   $$\lvert\tr(AU)\rvert=\lvert\tr(\lvert A\rvert VU)\rvert
   =\lvert\tr(\lvert A\rvert^{1/2} \underbrace{\lvert A\rvert^{1/2} VU}_{D})\rvert
   \le\sqrt{\tr(\lvert A\rvert^{1/2}\lvert A\rvert^{1/2})}\sqrt{\tr(D^\dagger D)},
   $$
   and putting in the explicit expression for $D$ you get the result.
2. ***(Via SVD)*** Another approach is to leverage the SVD of the operators. Notice that, if the SVD of $A$ reads
   $$A = \sum_i a_i |a_i^L\rangle\!\langle a_i^R|,$$
   then, for any unitary $U$, $AU$ is an operator which has the same singular values and left singular vectors as $A$. Similarly, $A$ and $UA$ have the same singular values and *right* singular vectors.
   The question to maximise $\lvert {\rm Tr}(AU)\rvert$ thus amounts to maximising
   $$\lvert{\rm Tr}(AU)\rvert = \left\lvert \sum_i a_i \langle u_i,a_i^L\rangle\right\rvert$$
   over the sets of orthonormal bases $\{\lvert u_i\rangle\}_i$. The connection with the above is via $|u_i\rangle=U^\dagger \lvert a_i^R\rangle$.
   From the above expression, it is clear that Cauchy-Schwarz implies
   $$\lvert{\rm Tr}(AU)\rvert \le \sum_i a_i = {\rm Tr}|A|,$$
   and that the maximum is achieved when $|u_i\rangle=|a_i^L\rangle$, that is, $U=\sum_i |a_i^R\rangle\!\langle a_i^L\rvert$.
3. ***(Via SVD, generalised result)*** Consider now a more general result, and let $A,B$ be generic matrices of type $A:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^m$ and $B:\mathbb{C}^m\to\mathbb{C}^n$.
   Note that we need this constraint on domains and codomains only because otherwise $\operatorname{tr}(AB)$ isn't well defined.
   We want to prove that $\lvert \operatorname{tr}(AB)\rvert \le \|A\|_{\rm op} \operatorname{tr}|B|$.
   To this end, write their SVDs as
   $$A = \sum_i a_i |a_i^L\rangle\!\langle a_i^R|,
   \qquad 
   U = \sum_i u_i |u_i^L\rangle\!\langle u_i^R|.$$
   Thus
   $$\lvert\operatorname{tr}(AB)\rvert =
   \lvert\sum_{i} a_i \langle a_i^R|B|a_i^L\rangle\rvert
   \le \sum_i a_i \lvert \langle a_i^R|B|a_i^L\rangle\rvert
   \le \|B\|_{\rm op}\operatorname{tr}|A|,$$
   where we used $\operatorname{tr}|A|=\sum_i a_i$ and $\lvert \langle v|B|w\rangle\rvert\le \|B\|_{\rm op}$ for any pair of normal vectors $|v\rangle,|w\rangle$.
   One could further characterise the $B$ that maximises $|\operatorname{tr}(AB)|$ among those operators with fixed operator norm $\|B\|_{\rm op}$, and from the above equation it's not surprising that this maximum is achieved with $B=\|B\|_{\rm op} \sum_i |a_i^R\rangle\!\langle a_i^L|$.

   In fact, this can be generalised even further, and seen as a special case of a "tracial matrix Holder inequality":
   $|\langle A,B\rangle|\le \|A\|_p\|B\|_p$ for $1/p+1/q=1$. See *e.g.* [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/248865/84108). See also [this other answer of mine](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/33653/55) for more rambling about operator norms.